# Helm/Vault/Kubernetes— How to interpolate a Helm variable within the Secret Path for Vault Sidecar Injector?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

Anyone here know how to properly interpolate a helm root-level value like  `.Release.Namespace` into a secrets path for Vault using the Vault Sidecar injector w/ `annotations` properly ?

What I have, but this is not interpolating in the first annotation successfully due to Helm notation (in a template file, not `values.yaml`)—

```
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-app-stuff: |
  {{`{{- with secret “kv/data/apps/MyApp/{{ .Release.Namespace }}” -}}
  export FOO=“{{ .Data.data.FOO }}”
  {{- end -}}`}}
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-app-stuff: ‘kv/data/apps/MyApp/{{ .Release.Namespace }}’
```

The second annotation resolves properly bc it’s a simple string but getting the secret path to resolve in the first one is the issue as it’s just interpreting the text as static :/ (e.g. `kv/data/apps/MyApp/{{ .Release.Namespace }}`)

Am I overlooking something silly or should I just re-think this piece altogether ?

Idea is that multiple versions of an app (dev/stage/etc.) will look under the same path up until the actual namespace for that app, tho really I think at its core this is a helm/interpolation technical question

Comment: Welcome to the community! Which `helm` version is used? Can you try to use it with [`variable`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/)?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the problem and managed to solve it, basically you wrap anything that needs to be interpreted literally as a string within {{` ... `}}, so in your case, this should work:

```
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-app-stuff: |
  {{`{{- with secret “kv/data/apps/MyApp/`}}{{ .Release.Namespace }}{{`” -}}
  export FOO=“{{ .Data.data.FOO }}”
  {{- end -}}`}}
```